# how to write to text file outside of netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm pretty sure someone has already asked this but i Can't find it. How can I write to a text file so that when i build the project from netbeans it'll still be able to write the file when its built into the .jar.
I was also having a problem reading file to .jar but found out i could use `InputStream` and `BufferedReader`. Is there something that can do this but with writing?
This is what I was using:

```
 printf=new PrintWriter(new File("Names.txt"));
```

but that doesn't work for writing outside of netbeans.
Edit:
The file is inside the classes of the jar file that I want to write to.

Comment: provide absolute path to write somewhere else, by this way it will write on current.directory

Comment: Example: printf=new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\somefolder\\Names.txt"));

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
FileOutputStream Output = new FileOutputStram("filename")
FileInputStream Input = new FileInputStream("filename")
```

Comment: And then you can use "Output.write(i)" and "Input.read(i)" to read/write to files

Answer (score 0):

Give absolute path like if you want it in d:/someFolder

```
printf=new PrintWriter(new File("d:/someFolder/Names.txt"));
```

Please read [this](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-relative-and-canonical-path-of-file-or-directory/60)